# A fully supported Bernoulli measure implies $p_i>0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\textbf{p}=(p_1, \ldots, p_k)$ be a probability vector. Assume that $\mu$ is a Bernoulli measure on $\{1, \ldots, k \}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Is it true that if $\mu$ is a fully supported Bernoulli measure, then $p_i>0$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, k \}$?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $\mu$ being a Bernoulli measure on $\{1, \dots, k\}^{\mathbb N}$? Also: what have you tried so far to solve the problem?